# Swift - How do I decode json from a REST API

Tags: ios, swift, networking, combine, urlsession

I am trying to make a GET from a REST API in swift. When I use the print statement (print(clubs)) I see the expected response in the proper format. But in the VC is gives me an empty array.

Here is the code to talk to the API

```
extension ClubAPI {

    public enum ClubError: Error {
        case unknown(message: String)
    }

    func getClubs(completion: @escaping ((Result<[Club], ClubError>) -> Void)) {
        let baseURL = self.configuration.baseURL
        let endPoint = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("/club")
        print(endPoint)
        API.shared.httpClient.get(endPoint) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                let clubs = (try? JSONDecoder().decode([Club].self, from: response.data)) ?? []
                print(clubs)
                completion(.success(clubs))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.unknown(message: error.localizedDescription)))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the code in the VC

```
private class ClubViewModel {
    @Published private(set) var clubs = [Club]()
    @Published private(set) var error: String?

    func refresh() {
        ClubAPI.shared.getClubs { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let club):
                print("We have \(club.count)")
                self.clubs = club
                print("we have \(club.count)")
            case .failure(let error):
                self.error = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the view controller code (Before the extension)

```
class ClubViewController: UIViewController {
    private var clubs = [Club]()
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private lazy var dataSource = makeDataSource()

    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    private var errorMessage: String? {
        didSet {

        }
    }
    private let viewModel = ClubViewModel()
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.subscriptions = [
            self.viewModel.$clubs.assign(to: \.clubs, on: self),
            self.viewModel.$error.assign(to: \.errorMessage, on: self)
        ]

        applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.viewModel.refresh()
    }



}




extension ClubViewController {
    typealias DataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Club>
    typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Club>
    func applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: Bool = true) {
        // Create a snapshot object.
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
        // Add the section
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        // Add the player array
        snapshot.appendItems(clubs)
        print(clubs.count)

        // Tell the dataSource about the latest snapshot so it can update and animate.
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animatingDifferences)
    }

    func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
        let dataSource = DataSource(tableView: tableView) { (tableView, indexPath, club) -> UITableViewCell? in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClubCell", for: indexPath)
            let club = self.clubs[indexPath.row]
            print("The name is \(club.name)")
            cell.textLabel?.text = club.name
            return cell
        }
        return dataSource
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the table view once you have assigned the value to `clubs` in your view controller. You can do this in your subscriber chain

Comment: @paulw11 Do you mean in the array? i.e self.subscriptions = [self.viewModel... collectionView.reloadData

Comment: I assume you are using a diffable data source. How have do you consume the data from the clubs array in that data source?  How do you tell the data source to apply a new snapshot when you assign values to the clubs array?  At the moment the code you have shown will assign the retrieved values to `clubs` but doesn't tell the tableview to do anything with it.

Comment: You can use a `sink` closure in your subscriber chain to execute code when the publisher fires

Comment: @Paulw11 I just updated the end of my question with the data source code.

Comment: So the only time you call `applySnapshot` is in `viewDidLoad` when `clubs` will be empty. You need to call this function in a `sink` closure rather than just using an `assign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a new snapshot to your table view once you have fetched the `clubs`.  Your current subscriber simply assigns a value to `clubs` and nothing more.

You can use a `sink` subscriber to assign the new `clubs` value and then call `applySnapshot`.  You need to ensure that this happens on the main queue, so you can use `receive(on:)`.

```
self.subscriptions = [
    self.viewModel.$clubs.receive(on: RunLoop.main).sink { clubs in
        self.clubs = clubs
        self.applySnapshot()
    },
    self.viewModel.$error.assign(to: \.errorMessage, on: self)
]
```